# How to get to c$ with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, administration

I'm trying to get to the admin share on a Windows 7 home machine from a Windows 7 home machine and nothing is working.  I enabled file and print sharing in the firewall and even turned Windows Firewall off.  I can get to the "Users" share that I remember setting up when I first installed.

When I go to \machinename\c$ instead of \machinename\users I get asked for a username and password and nothing works (not even machinename/adminuser).  \users works because I'm using the same username and password on both machines (like in the XP/2000 days).

Is the admin share c$ gone in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
add a new DWORD  called LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy and set it to 1 
reboot.
```

Delete it or remove the key when you don't want it anymore. Need i say from a security perspective this is suboptimal?

Filesharing needs to be allowed and the firewall need to be configured to allow that aswell.

Comment: Do I need to do this regedit to the remote machine as well as my machine?

Comment: To my knowledge, you need to do this on the machine which c$ you want to access over the network.

Answer (score 1):

It's not gone since I can access other Windows 7 C:\ drive remotely.

What I've done (I'm in a corporate domain) is I've disabled firewall (You should see 3 firewall options) these 3 options.

It's sounds quite simple but just with that, I can access C$

Give it a try